# Oracle ADF tree using master details transient VOs

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I am using Jdev 12.1.3

UseCase:

I want to display tree table by using transient VO's(Populating the rows Programmatically).

1. I have created two transient View Objects(1.Dept 2.Emp) and view link between this two.
2. And created a tree table based on this VO's which has two levels(Level 1 is Dept and Level 2 is Emp)
3. while loading the page i am populating the rows to View Object programmatically.
4. I am able to see the values in UI(Only for the Dept(root level)) and it doesn't contain any values for it's childs.
5. And also if i am dragging has different tree table for each VO. it is not showing the corresponding the values(like master child values.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you can build an af:tree component from 'standard' VO's: SQL based. If this is clear for you you can move on to:

1. make sure you understand how tree works. If you have a tree like:

   -a
   --ab
   --ac

(that means one root with two child nodes)
You will actually have 1 VO master instance and 2 child VO instances. This means you have to populate 2 View Object child instances.

If I was in your shoes and all I would need is to create a dynamic tree, I will create the tree programatically (http://one-size-doesnt-fit-all.blogspot.co.uk/2007/05/follow-up-programmatic-adf-faces-tree.html), dropping the programatic VOs.